# Regex from Numbers to GMT

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert -2 to GMT Timezone format.

Or maybe its possible to find the GMT with JavaScript?

**The result I need is:**

- from : -2
- to : -02:00

```
date = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60
console.log(date)

==> -2
```

Comment: Do you also have to convert `-2.5` to `-02:30` or `8.75` to `+08:45`?

Comment: nah only kinda integers like -4 to -04:00, 12 to 12:00, 5 to 05:00

Comment: So you're sure that there are no users from Newfoundland with timezone `-02:30` or Eucla with timezone `+08:45`? There are many more places all over the world with such non-integer timezones. What are the possible values? Integers in the range [-12, 12]?

Comment: I'll just cut it to the closest integer. My project is not meant to be 100% serious, more like a end bootcamp project. :) But good point there .. !

Comment: `date.replace(/\d/, (d => d.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':00'))`. But that won't work for all people from Iran, Nepal, Afghanistan, Myanmar, ... and some people from Canada, New Zealand, India, ... It should work in Venezuela for dates after 2016 but not before.

Comment: Im really that bad with regexs, how do you use that ? I replaced date with my variable this but it gives an error.
// const timezoneToGmt = timezone.replace(/\d/, (d => d.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':00'))

Comment: You have to convert `date` to a string: `date.toString().replace(/\d/, (d => d.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':00'))`. Just for clarification. The regex is `/\d/`. The other part is just basic JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem :

```
number1 = 5
number2 = -5
number3 = 11
number4 = -11
number5 = 0

const toGmt = (num) => {
  if ( (10 > num) && (num > 0) ) {
    return "(GMT+0"+num+":00)"
  } else if ( 10 <= num ) {
    return "(GMT+"+num+":00)" 
  } else if ( (0 > num) && (num > -10) ) {
    return "(GMT-0"+Math.abs(num)+":00)"
  } else if ( num <= -10 ){
    return "(GMT"+num+":00)"
  } else if ( num === 0 ){
    return "(GMT 0"+num+":00)"
  }
}

console.log(toGmt(number1)) ==> (GMT+05:00)
console.log(toGmt(number2)) ==> (GMT-05:00)
console.log(toGmt(number3)) ==> (GMT+11:00)
console.log(toGmt(number4)) ==> (GMT-11:00)
console.log(toGmt(number5)) ==> (GMT 00:00)
```